# de-register services from service discovery using steeltoe in .net framework 4.8

Tags: .net-4.8, service-discovery, steeltoe

I m trying to implement service discovery using Steeltoe in .net framework 4.8. I was able to register the service in Eureka but as the service stops, I am not able to remove it from the registry. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Steeltoe provides a `ShutdownAsync` method on `IDiscoveryClient` that will handle the de-registration. [Here's](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/2.x/Discovery/src/AspDotNet4/Fortune-Teller-Service4/Global.asax.cs#L38) an example of it being called in `Application_End()`.

It is worth noting that Visual Studio may not always do a graceful shutdown of your app, so sometimes shutdown events do not fire during local testing.

PS: Steeltoe is a bit of a niche library, so adding the `steeltoe` tag on any future questions should help a lot with getting faster answers!